# retrieve keycloak SSO session idle

Tags: java, keycloak

I am using Keycloak 17 to authenticate.
I would like to warn the user about the session Idle timeout.
Is there a way to programmatically retrieve the **SSO Session idle** time from the configuration?

[*Edit*] After looking at the sources, I found this in **RealmModel**: *realm.SsoSessionIdleTimeout*, but I don't know how to reach its value after the user logged in.
I have tried with the keycloak object like in this example, which returns 0:
`keycloak.tokenManager().refreshToken().getRefreshExpiresIn()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you can retrieve the value using `myRealm.getSsoSessionIdleTimeout()`. In order to pass it to the user you can set it in the access/id token using a [oidc mapper](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/mappers/AbstractOIDCProtocolMapper.java#L36).

You can see a simple example in [this excellent repo](https://github.com/thomasdarimont/keycloak-extension-playground/blob/master/simple-oidc-mapper/src/main/java/com/github/thomasdarimont/keycloak/oidc/mapper/simple/SimpleOidcMapper.java).

Don't forget to add this mapper to your client/default scope otherwise it will not be included in the tokens.